# What are alternatives to JVM exceptions for reporting and handling errors in clojure code?

Tags: exception, error-handling, clojure, reporting, conditional-statements

**Background**

The book The Joy of Clojure explains how JVM exceptions are a closed system and suggests that there may be better alternatives for reporting and handling errors in clojure. From my experience, the common lisp condition system seems ideal, however, I am not restricting answers to this paradigm. From what I've researched there are conditions (Gilardi) http://clojure.github.com/clojure-contrib/condition-api.html , error-kit (Chouser) http://richhickey.github.com/clojure-contrib/error-kit-api.html, and handler (Weiss) https://gist.github.com/745223, however there does not appear to be a clear winner among these implementations and I feel more information on topic would be useful.

How have existing alternatives been successfully used in projects? I'm looking for examples to emulate.

How do these alternative systems overcome limitations with the JVM exception system?

What are the future directions or what are experimental alternatives on the horizon and what they entail?

Comment: See http://groups.google.com/group/clojure-dev/browse_thread/thread/734ee59f6cbc1b55 and http://dev.clojure.org/display/design/Exception+Handling

Comment: Current discussion on topic: http://dev.clojure.org/display/design/Error+Handling+References

Answer (score 2):

FYI, this is being discussed in clojure-dev.  Ideas collecting [here](http://dev.clojure.org/display/design/Exception+Handling) and thread [here](http://groups.google.com/group/clojure-dev/browse_thread/thread/734ee59f6cbc1b55).

Comment: Thanks, I'll try synthesize the results of the discussion when its done.

Answer (score 0):

Many years have passed since the question was asked, but I think the topic is still relevant. I have been working on [Promenade](https://github.com/kumarshantanu/promenade) (see [documentation](https://cljdoc.org/d/promenade/)) that can express error as data and provides elegant error handling and control flow. There are also other projects (mentioned on Promenade README) trying to address the same issue.